# MSQL PDO update issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am new to PDO. How do i do a UPDATE SQL Command? 
ERROR MESSAGE given - 
Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( email, givenname, surname,' at line 1

```
 <?php                  
    ob_start(); 
    require("config.php");  
        if(!empty($_POST)) 
        { 
            // Check if the username is already taken
            $query = " 
                SELECT 
                    1 
                FROM users 
                WHERE 
                    email = :email 
            "; 
            $query_params = array( ':email' => $_POST['email'] ); 
            try { 
                $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
                $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
            } 
            catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); } 
            $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
            if($row){ die("This email is already in use"); } 


            // Check if the mobile number is already taken
            $query = " 
                SELECT 
                    1 
                FROM users 
                WHERE 
                    mobilenumber = :mobilenumber 
            "; 
            $query_params = array( ':mobilenumber' => $_POST['mobilenumber'] ); 
            try { 
                $stmt = $db->prepare($query);       
                $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
            } 
            catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); } 
            $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
            if($row){ die("This Mobile Number is already in use"); }  
            //Add row to database 


            $query = " 
                UPDATE users ( 
                    email,
                    givenname,
                    surname,
                    gender,
                    dateofbirth,
                    nric,
                    nationality,                
                    race,
                    address,
                    postalcode,
                    mobilenumber,
                    profession

                ) SET ( 
                    :email, 
                    :givenname,
                    :surname,
                    :gender,
                    :dateofbirth,
                    :nric,
                    :nationality,
                    :race,
                    :address,
                    :postalcode,
                    :mobilenumber,
                    :profession          

                    WHERE (
                    'id' = $id)
                ) 
            "; 

            $query_params = array( 
                ':email' => $_POST['email'], 
                ':givenname' => ucwords($_POST['givenname']),            
                ':surname' => ucwords($_POST['surname']), 
                ':gender' => $_POST['gender'], 
                ':dateofbirth' => $_POST['dateofbirth'], 
                ':nric' => strtoupper($_POST['nric']),
                ':nationality' => $_POST['nationality'],           
                ':race' => ucwords($_POST['race']), 
                ':address' => ucwords($_POST['address']), 
                ':postalcode' => $_POST['postalcode'], 
                ':mobilenumber' => $_POST['mobilenumber'], 
                ':profession' => ucwords($_POST['profession']) 

            ); 
            try {  
                $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
                $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
            } 
            catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); } 
            header("Location: myaccount.php"); 
            die("Redirecting to myaccount.php"); 
        }                              
    ?>


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>           
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../assets/ico/favicon.png">

        <title>Homepage</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">


        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="../../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
          <script src="../../assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

          <style>
        #tablenotcenter {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0;
      width: 100%;
      text-align:left;

    } 
                </style>
      </head>              

      <body>

      <?php 
    if (empty($_SESSION['user']))
     {
     include_once("header.php");
     }
    else     {
          include_once("header2.php");
          }?>


    <div class="page-header">

    <div class="container">
    <h1> My Account </h1>     
    <hr class="colorgraph">
          <?php $username123 = htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>          

      <?php


      include ("DBScripts/DB.php");
              $conn = dbConnect();
                 if (!$conn)
             die("Couldn't connect to MySQL");
         $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from users WHERE username='$username123'");
         $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 

            $id= $row["id"];
             $username= $row["username"];
              $email   = $row["email"]; 
                $givenname= $row["givenname"];
                  $surname = $row["surname"];
                    $gender = $row["gender"];
                      $dateofbirth= $row["dateofbirth"];
                        $nric  = $row["nric"];
                         $nationality = $row["nationality"];
                          $race = $row["race"];
                           $address = $row["address"];
                            $postalcode = $row["postalcode"];
                             $mobilenumber = $row["mobilenumber"];
                              $profession = $row["profession"];
                                    $membersince = $row["membersince"];
                                          $lastlogin = $row["lastlogin"];



    ?>



             <form method="post">
     <table class="table table-hover"  id="tablenotcenter" border="0">
        <tr >
        <td><div class="pull-left"><h3 class="text-primary"> Personal Information </h3></div></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>                             
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Given Name:</strong></td>
        <td> <input name="givenname" type="text" maxlength="20" value="<?echo $givenname?>" style="width: 250px; height: 20px"  pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,20}" required/></td>
        <td><strong>Race</strong></td>
        <td><input name="race" type="text" maxlength="20" value="<? echo $race ?>" style="width: 250px; height: 20px" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,20}" required/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Surname:</strong></td>
        <td><input name="surname" type="text" maxlength="20" value="<? echo $surname ?>" style="width: 250px; height: 20px"  pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,20}" required/></td>
        <td><strong>Address</strong></td>
        <td><input name="address" type="text" maxlength="50" value="<? echo $address ?>" style="width: 250px; height: 20px"  required/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Gender:</strong></td>
        <td>       <?
              if ($gender =="M") 
              {             ?>

     <div class="radio-inline">

      <label>

        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male" checked required>

        Male

      </label>

    </div>
    <div class="radio-inline">

      <label>

        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="Female" required>

        Female

      </label>

    </div>
    <? } else {?>
              <div class="radio-inline">

      <label>

        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="Male" required>

        Male

      </label>

    </div>
    <div class="radio-inline">

      <label>

        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="Female" checked required>

        Female

      </label>

    </div>

     <? }?>








       </td>

        <td><strong>Postal Code</strong></td>
        <td><input name="postalcode" type="text" maxlength="20" value="<? echo $postalcode ?>" style="width: 250px; height: 20px" pattern="[0-9]{6}" required/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Date Of Birth:</strong></td>
        <td>   <input type="date" name="dateofbirth" value="<? echo $dateofbirth?>" max="1997-12-31" required>  </td>

        <td><strong>Mobile Number</strong></td>
        <td><input name="mobilenumber" type="text" maxlength="20" value="<? echo $mobilenumber ?>" style="width: 250px; height: 20px"  pattern="[0-9]{8}" required/></td>
      </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><strong>Nationality:</strong></td>
        <td>  <input name="nationality" type="text" maxlength="20" value="<? echo $nationality ?>" style="width: 250px; height: 20px" required/> </td>

        <td><strong>Profession:</strong></td>
        <td><input name="profession" type="text" maxlength="20" value="<? echo $profession ?>" style="width: 250px; height: 20px"  pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,20}" required/></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td colspan="4"><div class="pull-left"><h3 class="text-primary"> Account Setting </h3></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>ID</strong></td>
        <td><? echo $id?></td>
        <td><strong>Email:</strong></td>
        <td><input name="email" type="text" maxlength="20" value="<? echo $email ?>" style="width: 250px; height: 20px" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}" required/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Password:</strong></td>
        <td><a href= changepassword.php> <span class="label label-primary">Change Password</span>
    </a></td>
        <td><strong>Memeber Since</strong></td>
        <td><? echo $membersince ?></td>

        <table border="0">
      <tr>                                             
        <td><input name="id" type="hidden" maxlength="20" value="<? echo $id?>" style="width: 250px; height: 20px" required/></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>                              
        <td><div class="pull-right"><a href="myaccountedit.php">  <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button></a> </div></td>
      </tr>       

    </table>







             </form>
      </div>  
        </div>
             <?php include_once("footer.php");?>

      </body> 
      <? ob_flush()?>
    </html>
```

Comment: `//Add row to database`?  Do you mean to `INSERT INTO`, rather than `UPDATE`?

Comment: You need to learn basic debugging techniques. You clearly get a syntax error in your SQL code—it's very unlikely that your HTML code has anything to do with it.

Comment: @eggyal i meant it for update. im using the code from insert.

Comment: I hope you don't take this the wrong way, as it is meant only by way of support, but it very much feels as though you are attempting to jump head-first into water that is far deeper than that in which you are capable of swimming.  There are a great many problems with the code that you have pasted, indicating that you may not understand much of what is going on; coupled with your inability to reduce the code to a concise example of the problem that you are experiencing, one very much feels that you should take a step back and start with some basic PHP/MySQL tutorials before delving any further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) is syntactically incorrect. you should do:

```sql
UPDATE users
SET email = :email,
  givenname = :givenname,
  surname = :surname,
  gender = :gender,
  dateofbirth = :dateofbirth,
  nric = :nric,
  nationality = :nationality,
  race = :race,
  address = :address,
  postalcode = :postalcode,
  mobilenumber = :mobilenumber,
  profession = :profession
WHERE id = $ID
```

Comment: Where a string literal is equal to a PHP variable that has been in-lined into the SQL?  Really?

Comment: Wasn't looking at that part. Was only fixing the fields for the SET. :p

Comment: It isn't clear where `$ID` is defined, but in any event I'd hazard a guess that it ought to be parameterised (for good practice if nothing else).

Comment: I'm not very fluent in php, so that part i'm not going to venture on guessing.

Comment: WHERE username = $username1337 /  $username1337 = htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); //////  here is the error message ///// Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'test' in 'where clause'

Comment: @user2968597. I'm not sure what you got there, but that's probably what eggyal was saying. You should probably use WHERE username = :username and add :username to the query_params.

Comment: WHERE id = :id /// Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens  //// tokens?????

Comment: you should add :id at the end of query_params and what is it's value.

Comment: ok i got it working already! thanks for the help! appreciated! :D

Answer (score 0):

that's the wrong syntax for update - update is

```
update `table` set field = value, another_field = another_value
```

what you've got there is the syntax for insert